# Can not install Ubuntu Phone on Nexus 4

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I follow the [instruction](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/)
 and everything seemed to work ok but then the phone reboots at the end with a message saying "This phone needs restoring from a PC or service center".

So I can flash back to the Android 4.4.4 "KitKat" and everything works ok.
Actually from the boot I can launch the recovery boot which is the ubuntu one but I am not able to launch the ubuntu OS...

I tried the stable and development channel.

```
ubuntu-device-flash touch --channel=ubuntu-touch/devel/ubuntu --bootstrap
2016/03/06 11:08:00 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2016/03/06 11:08:00 Device is |mako|
2016/03/06 11:08:00 Flashing version 8 from ubuntu-touch/devel/ubuntu channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device mako
19.04 MB / 19.04 MB [====================================] 100.00 % 301.97 KB/s 
52.43 MB / 52.43 MB [====================================] 100.00 % 408.69 KB/s 
288.72 MB / 288.72 MB [==================================] 100.00 % 437.31 KB/s 
2016/03/06 11:19:39 Start pushing /home/splater/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/ubuntu-0144c0d9ab780d8b40477987c3004d4c25d1861e6dd067125e77970c11ec76a1.tar.xz to device
2016/03/06 11:19:39 Start pushing /home/splater/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2016/03/06 11:19:39 Start pushing /home/splater/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/custom-9cebce4a630edb99402c79c73a7eb7eed051febe93e66208c6711f29f6d5cf35.tar.xz to device
2016/03/06 11:19:39 Start pushing /home/splater/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/devel/ubuntu/mako/version-8.tar.xz to device
2016/03/06 11:19:39 Start pushing /home/splater/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-00f7ea9bb6e1b445460b981872b273c4a49cea282a4478831543ccf9d83d7ab2.tar.xz to device
2016/03/06 11:19:39 Start pushing /home/splater/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
2016/03/06 11:19:40 Done pushing /home/splater/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/devel/ubuntu/mako/version-8.tar.xz to device
2016/03/06 11:19:40 Done pushing /home/splater/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz to device
2016/03/06 11:19:40 Done pushing /home/splater/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz to device
2016/03/06 11:21:10 Done pushing /home/splater/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/custom-9cebce4a630edb99402c79c73a7eb7eed051febe93e66208c6711f29f6d5cf35.tar.xz to device
2016/03/06 11:22:56 Done pushing /home/splater/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-00f7ea9bb6e1b445460b981872b273c4a49cea282a4478831543ccf9d83d7ab2.tar.xz to device
2016/03/06 11:29:08 Done pushing /home/splater/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/ubuntu-0144c0d9ab780d8b40477987c3004d4c25d1861e6dd067125e77970c11ec76a1.tar.xz to device
2016/03/06 11:29:08 Created ubuntu_command: /home/splater/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu_commands129934107
2016/03/06 11:29:08 Rebooting into recovery to flash
```

On the boot I can see:

```
Bootloader version MAKOZ30d
SECURE BOOT - enabled
LOCK STATE - unlocked
```

is the secure boot is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try the rc channel for mako, or bq aquaris channel (I'm on bq aquaris RC proposed on nexus 4). First flash the latest radio from the android 5.1.1 images. I couldn't get stable to boot when I first installed either.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you answered yourself: the secure boot is the problem. Even if the instructions on developer.ubuntu.com are quite complete, I found these video tutorials more useful.

1. http://pocketnow.com/2013/02/22/install-ubuntu-nexus-4
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=13WFcVmDfZg

Comment: Thank you but I looked at the videos and I can see a) on one video that the secure boot is also Enabled in his nexus 4  b) the actual installation has nothing comparable with these video. I assume the actual installation is way simpler but perhaps is buggy for Nexus 4 ??

Comment: @Laurent Curious, did secure boot end up being the barrier? I am wondering if I need to disable it on my nexus 5.